# mysql cartesian product tuning performance

Tags: mysql, sql

a premise: the result of the cartesian product of 3 tables of about 5'000 rows (I would love to go as high as 50'000 rows) is for a little program that i am writing...so all server tuning options will be for this one task. the server wont be needed in a "normal online use".

So i ask, what system variables do i need to change for this very particular one time task?

(as example: does changing the number of instances or the size of the chunks help for this task? maybe set join_buffer_size=to 10GB?)

On the other hand , (fortunately?) I have a where condition which could help reduce the burden. This is the sql string:

```
SELECT tbl1.*, tbl2. *, tbl3. * 
FROM  tbl1, tbl2, tbl3
WHERE Ma1 >= (Ma70 + Ma71 + Ma72) AND 
      Ma2 >= (Ma80 + Ma81 + Ma82) AND
      Ma3 >= (Ma90 + Ma91 + Ma92) AND
      MOD((Ma130 + Ma131 + Ma132), 180) = 0
```

tbl1,tbl2 and tbl3 have 15 columns each. in particular:

- tbl1 has columns Ma1,Ma70,Ma80,Ma90,Ma130
- tbl2 has columns Ma2,Ma71,Ma81,Ma91,Ma131
- tbl3 has columns Ma3,Ma72,Ma82,Ma92,Ma132

(btw. I used indexes on all 3 tables and the optimizer did use them, but, on a smaller test sample(500 rows) the difference in fetch time was really insignificant (from 18 sec. to 12).  Maybe i used the indexes wrong)

Comment: Your query cannot be optimized.  The conditions are too complex.

Comment: Thank you for your quick replay!...So only tuning the server for this "too complex" query can maybe help. Adjust which system variables for complex cross joins?

Comment: This sounds like a problem of poor schema design.

Comment: i tried to explain...im "abusing" of mysql for my personal use...mysql wont be used as server...i dont care about "poor schema design".  Its all about "calculations". As mentioned in the title:"cartesian product"...and how to tune mysql so its tuned to do _only_ cross joins/"cartesian product". the 3 tables have no relations _per definition_

Comment: @simcity . . . You are attempting an optimization problem using SQL.  It is just not the right tool.  Judging from the query, you need some sort of gradient descent or simplex algorithm -- things that are far outside the remit of SQL.

Comment: I appreciate you all taking your time to answer my question, but my question is very simple : what system variables do i need to change to make mysql tuned to perform at its maximum to handle _big_ cross joins? I don't need complicated gradient descent or simplex algorithm as suggested...i need :"cartesian product"/cross join. should i set 
1.the number of instances to 1 or 2.change the size of the chunks? 3. maybe set join_buffer_size=to 10GB?